# Android and Azure Read from _deleted

Tags: android, azure

so I'm learning microsoft azure, and I'm trying to understand the reading from columns, now I'm able to do that with a new column I've made, but I'm trying to obtain all values from my text column, based on the whichever one is deleted looking at the _deleted column (Automatically made by azure).

Currently I am doing it as follows:

```
        mClient.getTable(Item.class).where().field("_deleted").eq(false)
            .execute(new TableQueryCallback<Item>() {
                public void onCompleted(List<Item> result,
                                        int count,
                                        Exception exception,
                                        ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                    if (exception == null) {
                        for (Item item : result) {
                            Log.i("ITEM", "Read object with ID " + item.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

If I use other field and eq values I can confirm it works. But I can't seem to get this to work with the _deleted column and was hoping if anyone had some insights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies guys, turns out I did a super noob mistake, the column "_deleted" is actually "__deleted" I couldn't see those two underscores there since the text was quite small. *Hits palm into face*